# Single MySql query to update any value (or values) of particular row in table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am writing a php based webservice for updating the registration records in register table. Below I have mentioned structure of **'register'** table.

```
CREATE TABLE `register` (
  `ID` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `mobile_num` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_of_birth` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Now I wan't to modify any of the declared field (column) for provided ID. The case is such that, I can update single column value or I can update N number of columns. But I want to write a single query for that.

In my POST request I am sending a fields only that being changed. Other fields are null. Now Consider following cases

**Case_1:** If I want to update `date_of_birth` and `password`, I am only sending these two values in POST request and other fields are null.

**Case_2:** If I want to update only `gender`, then I am only sending value for `gender` in POST request and other fields are null.

**PROBLEM:**

During updatingg whats happenning is, the values I am sending in POST are only gets updated. Remaining fields gets updated to null. What I am thinking is that, If I wan't to modify only couple of values, why to send other fields in POST that I don't wan't to modify. It is just a waste of data during upload. Below is my update query in PHP.

```
  public function updateReg($requestMethod) {
    if ($requestMethod !== "POST") {
      $this->showError($this->contentTypeForResponse, "Request method should be POST.");
    }

    $postArray = $_POST;     // in case for form data or url encoded data
    // $postArray = $this->jsonValidate($this->contentTypeForResponse, file_get_contents('php://input'));
    if (empty($postArray)) {
      $this->showError($this->contentTypeForResponse, "Parameters are missing.");
    }

    $id = isset($postArray["id"]) ? $postArray["id"] : $this->showError($this->contentTypeForResponse, "key 'id' missing.");    
    $firstName = isset($postArray["firstName"]) ? $postArray["firstName"] : null;
    $lastName = isset($postArray["lastName"]) ? $postArray["lastName"] : null;
    $email = isset($postArray["email"]) ? $postArray["email"] : null;
    $password = isset($postArray["password"]) ? $postArray["password"] : null;
    $gender = isset($postArray["gender"]) ? $postArray["gender"] : null;
    $mobileNumber = isset($postArray["mobileNumber"]) ? $postArray["mobileNumber"] : null;
    $dob = isset($postArray["dob"]) ? $postArray["dob"] : null;

    $stmt = $this->connection->prepare("UPDATE " . TABLE_REG . " SET "
            . REG_FNAME . " = :firstName" . ", "
            . REG_LNAME . " = :lastName" . ", "
            . REG_EMAIL . " = :email" . ", "
            . REG_PSW . " = :password" . ", "
            . REG_GENDER . " = :gender" . ", "
            . REG_MOBILE_NUM . " = :mobileNumber" . ", "
            . REG_DOB . " = :dob" //. ", "    // uncomment if their are multiple
            . " WHERE "
            . REG_ID . " = :id" // . " AND " // uncomment for more filters
            );
    $stmt->bindParam(":firstName", $firstName);
    $stmt->bindParam(":lastName", $lastName);
    $stmt->bindParam(":email", $email);
    $stmt->bindParam(":password", $password);
    $stmt->bindParam(":gender", $gender);
    $stmt->bindParam(":mobileNumber", $mobileNumber);
    $stmt->bindParam(":dob", $dob);
    $stmt->bindParam(":id", $id);
    $success = $stmt->execute();

    if ($success === FALSE) {
      $this->connection = null;
      $this->showError($this->contentTypeForResponse, "Profile updation failed. Please try again.");
    }

    $this->connection = null;

    $result = array(
        "title" => "Success!",
        "message" => "Profile saved successfully."
    );
    $this->showSuccess($this->contentTypeForResponse, "EDIT PROFILE", $result);
  }
```

**Question:** How to write a single mysql query that can modify a single value or multiple values that are provided in POST request, without altering other values?

Comment: when you are updating you will show all the values in form right?which belongs to the particular userid

Comment: You could get the data from your database, compare your $_POST to the data and build a query that only contains fields that have changed

Comment: If you don’t want to _read_ the existing values from the database first, so that you could set those again in your update statement, then I don’t think there is any other way than creating that statement dynamically in the first place - so that it explicitly only contains the columns you want to change to begin with, or uses `colname=colname` in those places, instead of a (new) value. But your parameter binding would have to take that into account as well.

Comment: @CBroe - Thanks for your valuable reply. I already tried with the way you provided. But I think I can do something better than this.

Comment: @CBroe - Exactly. I am also trying using that way. Same thing is explained by Igor Ilic in answer.

Comment: Yeah, saw that afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on accepted answer and changes mentioned by CBRoe, below is my working answer.

```
class registerHelper extends dbHelper {

  // properties
  private $contentTypeForResponse;
  private $connection;
  private $tableMapper;

  // constructor
  public function __construct($contentTypeForResponse) {
    $this->contentTypeForResponse = $contentTypeForResponse;
    $this->connection = $this->getConnection($contentTypeForResponse);
    $this->tableMapper = array(
        "id" => REG_ID,
        "firstName" => REG_FNAME,
        "lastName" => REG_LNAME,
        "email" => REG_EMAIL,
        "password" => REG_PSW,
        "gender" => REG_GENDER,
        "mobileNumber" => REG_MOBILE_NUM,
        "avatar" => REG_AVATAR_URL,
        "createdAt" => REG_CREATED_AT,
        "updatedAt" => REG_UPDATED_AT,
        "mobileVerified" => REG_IS_MOB_VERIFY,
        "emailVerified" => REG_IS_EMAIL_VERIFY,
        "dob" => REG_DOB
    );
  }

  public function updateReg($requestMethod) {
    if ($requestMethod !== "POST") {
      $this->showError($this->contentTypeForResponse, "Request method should be POST.");
    }

    $postArray = $_POST;     // in case for form data or url encoded data
    // $postArray = $this->jsonValidate($this->contentTypeForResponse, file_get_contents('php://input'));
    if (empty($postArray)) {
      $this->showError($this->contentTypeForResponse, "Parameters are missing.");
    }

    $queryParam = array();
    $queryParam["id"] = isset($postArray["id"]) ? $postArray["id"] : $this->showError($this->contentTypeForResponse, "key 'id' missing.");

    // check here whether user already exists or not
    $this->isIdExists($queryParam["id"]);

    $queryParam["avatar"] = isset($_FILES["avatar"]) ? $this->uploadImage($this->contentTypeForResponse, $_FILES["avatar"]) : null;
    $queryParam["password"] = isset($postArray["password"]) ? $postArray["password"] : null;
    $queryParam["firstName"] = isset($postArray["firstName"]) ? $postArray["firstName"] : null;
    $queryParam["lastName"] = isset($postArray["lastName"]) ? $postArray["lastName"] : null;
    $queryParam["gender"] = isset($postArray["gender"]) ? $postArray["gender"] : null;
    $queryParam["mobileNumber"] = isset($postArray["mobileNumber"]) ? $postArray["mobileNumber"] : null;
    $queryParam["dob"] = isset($postArray["dob"]) ? $postArray["dob"] : null;
    $queryParam["updatedAt"] = $this->getDateTime("UTC", "UTC", DateTime::ATOM, $this->contentTypeForResponse);
    $queryParam["emailVerified"] = isset($postArray["emailVerified"]) ? $postArray["emailVerified"] : null;
    $queryParam["mobileVerified"] = isset($postArray["mobileVerified"]) ? $postArray["mobileVerified"] : null;

    $query = "UPDATE " . TABLE_REG . " SET ";
    foreach ($queryParam as $key => $value) {
      if ($key === "id" || is_null($value)) {
        continue;
      }
      $query .= $this->tableMapper[$key] . " = :" . $key . ", ";
    }
    $query = rtrim($query, ", ") . " WHERE "
            . REG_ID . " = :id"; // . " AND " // uncomment for more filters

    $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query);
    foreach ($queryParam as $key => $value) {
      if (is_null($value)) {
        continue;
      }
      $stmt->bindParam(":" . $key, $queryParam[$key]);
    }
    $success = $stmt->execute();

    if ($success === FALSE) {
      $this->connection = null;
      $this->showError($this->contentTypeForResponse, "Profile updation failed. Please try again.");
    }

    $this->connection = null;

    $result = array(
        "title" => "Success!",
        "message" => "Profile updated successfully."
    );
    $this->showSuccess($this->contentTypeForResponse, "EDIT PROFILE", $result);
  }

  private function isIdExists($id) {
    $stmt = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT " . REG_EMAIL . " FROM " . TABLE_REG . " WHERE "
            . REG_ID . " = :id");
    $stmt->bindParam(":id", $id);
    $success = $stmt->execute();

    if ($success === FALSE) {
      $this->connection = null;
      $this->showError($this->contentTypeForResponse, "Failed at User ID exists check. Please try again.");
    }

    // $this->connection = null;
    // set the resulting array to associative
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if (empty($result) === TRUE) {
      $this->connection = null;
      $this->showError($this->contentTypeForResponse, "Specified 'id' not found in users table. Please provide correct ID.");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this:

```
<?php

$query = "UPDATE " . TABLE_REG . " SET ";

foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    if(is_null($value))
        continue; 

    $query .= "{$key} = :{$key}, ";
}

$query = rtrim($query, ", ");
$stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query);

foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    if(is_null($value))
       continue;

    $stmt->bindParam(":{$key}", $value);
}

$success = $stmt->execute();
```

This way you will only form an update statement for fields that are not null

Comment: looking interesting. I have not tried by this way. But I think, this is what I am looking for. But I have to try it first. Will let you know soon.

Comment: Should probably add a white list of allowed column names to that though; otherwise an attacker might be able to change the values of columns they weren’t supposed to to begin with (or just to provoke errors by providing a non-existing column name.)

Comment: @CBroe - Yes you are right. But in my webservice I am going to create a mapper (key -> value) to match POST Filed with actual column name. Otherwise unfortunately I have to pass information in POST request with actual Column names.

Comment: @Igor Ilic - Thanks for your answer. It works. But I made some changes into your answer to avoid problems suggested by CBroe. You can also check my answer which I posted.